# date_i18n() doesn't work when using filter load_textdomain_mofile()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, translation

I declare a filter in the main file of my Wordpress plugin like this :

```php
function load_plugin_textdomain_for_translations()
{
    $langCode = detecterLangueNavigateur();
    $mofile = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/lang/my-plugin-' . $langCode . '.mo';
    return $mofile;
}

add_filter('load_textdomain_mofile', 'load_plugin_textdomain_for_translations', 10, 2);
```

I did it in this way because I wanted to put the language from the browser. If I don't put this filter the language doesn't change depend the browser and stay with the default language of the wordpress site. (Maybe there is another way I'm not very familiar with Wordpress).

But when I declare this filter, only all my date wrapped with `date_i18n()` are not translated anymore. It stays in English  regardless of the browser language.

I do surely something wrong, any idea please ?

I tried to take the default translations of .mo file located in wp-content/languages/fr_FR.mo to put in my own .mo file. But it doesn't work.

If I remove the filter the `date_i18n()` works but by logic all my translations doesn't work anymore.